# Adding Custom Icon for CyanogenMod Users in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-layout, cyanogenmod

My app icon do not look good on CyanogenMod devices running the default theme. CyanogenMod theme engine takes the normal icon and try to create an icon that fits the theme. In the case of my app, the result is bad.

Is it possible to package an icon with the app to be used for user running CyanogenMod, possibly for specific themes?

If it is possible, pointers on how to do that are welcome.

Comment: Anyone with an answer to this question?

Comment: I do not think it is possible to specify apk resources for CM, and generally it is not a good idea. Do other apps suffer from the same issue? May be some look good in CM app launcher (Trebuchet AFAIK), so you could use the same approach with your icon.

Comment: Apps who have their icon in the icon package look good for the other one it usually okay, and for a couple like mine it doesn't play properly. I'll be happy to add a icon to my apk to be picked up.
Note that this is for CM11, in CM12 the square icons have disappeared and the icon look good again.

Comment: Hey! Did you find any solution to this problem? I am also facing similar issue. My app's logo is getting messed up on Cyanogen and also on Oneplus one default theme, Hexo theme.

Comment: Nope haven't found any solution, but later version of Cynamogen do not override the logo anymore, at least the one I have tried with.